# UWP ECDSP Signature

Tags: c#, cryptography, uwp, ecdsa

I want to make a ECDSA signature with this code :

```
AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider objAsymmAlgProv = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.EcdsaSha256);
CryptographicKey keypair = objAsymmAlgProv.CreateKeyPairWithCurveName(EccCurveNames.SecP256r1);
BinaryStringEncoding encoding = BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8;
buffMsg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary("Test Message", encoding);
IBuffer buffSIG = CryptographicEngine.Sign(keypair, buffMsg);
byte [] SignByteArray = buffSIG.ToArray();
bool res = CryptographicEngine.VerifySignature(keypair, buffMsg, buffSIG);
```

`VerifySignature` always returns true and this is ok.

But I have some problems with signature.

Why is length of signature ( `SignByteArray`) fixed? (0x40 byte).

And Why are `SignByteArray [0]` and `SignByteArray [2]` values incorrect? (I think they should be 0x30 and 0x02)

I expected a thing like https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/sample-ecdsa.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ECDSA specification concludes with a determination that the pair (`r`, `s`) are the signature.  What it neglects to do is indicate how one should write them down.

Windows and .NET use the IEEE (P)1363 format, which is big-endian `r` concat big-endian `s`.  `r` and `s` have the same size (determined by the key size), so the signature is always even in length and r is the first half.

OpenSSL uses an ASN.1/DER encoding, which is SEQUENCE(INTEGER(r), INTEGER(s)).  The DER encoding can go all the way down to 6 bytes (`30 04 02 00 02 00`, in the degenerate r=0, s=0) and is, on average, 6 bytes bigger than the IEEE form.  It encodes as `30 [length, one or more bytes] 02 [length, one or more bytes] [optional padding 00] [big-endian r with no leading 00s] 02 [length, one or more bytes] [optional padding 00] [big-endian s with no leading 00s]`.

The DER form is too data dependant to specifically describe, so an example should help.  Assuming we're using a curve in a 32-bit field and we generate (r=1016, s=2289644760).

IEEE 1363:

```
// r
00 00 03 F8
// s
88 79 34 D8
```

DER:

```
SEQUENCE(INTEGER(1016), INTEGER(2289644760))

// Encode r
// 1016 => 0x3F8 => 03 F8 (length 02)
SEQUENCE(
    02 02
       03 F8,
    INTEGER(2289644760))

// Encode s
// 2289644760 => 0x887934D8 => 88 79 34 D8
// But since the high bit is set this is a negative number (-2005322536),
// and s is defined to be positive.  So insert a 00 to ensure the high bit is clear.
//   => 00 88 79 34 D8 (length 05)
SEQUENCE(
    02 02
       03 F8
    02 05
       00 88 79 34 D8)

// And encode the sequence, whose payload length we can now count as 11 (0B)
30 0B
   02 02
      03 F8
   02 05
      00 88 79 34 D8
```

So Windows/.NET emit `00 00 03 F8 88 79 34 D8`, and OpenSSL emits `30 0B 02 02 03 F8 02 05 00 88 79 34 D8`. But they're both just saying `(r, s) = (1016, 2289644760)`.

(Aside: Your observation that signature[2] == 0x02 in the DER encoding is correct for the size key you're working with, but at around a 496-bit key the SEQUENCE length becomes statistically likely to require more than one byte; so for a P-521 key it's most likely that it starts as `03 81 88 02`, with variability in the `88` byte)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!